# scrollable div with fixed element inside

Tags: jquery, css, html, positioning

please have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/devboell/kjFps/

I need to make a div, whose contents will overflow both horizontally and vertically.
There also needs to be an element that will scroll along horizontally, but remain fixed vertically.

To explain the code:

- there is a main `container` div, and at first I had a single `background` div that is double the size of the `container` in x and y direction.
- the `scale` div is the element that should always be visible at the top of the `container`, but should scroll horizontally.
- my thought was to divide the `background` div in a `backgroundHorizontal` and `backgroundVertical`, and then position the `scale` absolutely in the `backgroundHorizontal`.
- still, when scrolling down, the `backgroundVertical` pushes the `scale` up and out of view.

There is also a further requirement, and although I don't want to ask two questions at the same time, I think I should mention it because it might influence the solution for this problem. The requirement is that the vertical scrollbar should alway be visible, and not only when you scroll all the way to the right, like it does now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the similar problem, and can say that according to specification it ia impossible to have div scrollable horizontaly, and fixed vertically at once time.

The solution I used is like:
1. set inside element position to absolue;

$.('container').on('scroll', function(){

$('.inside-element').css('left', $.('container').scrollLeft())

})

Comment: ye, I was afraid of that, although your solution is clean enough as well. I'll wait to see if anyone else responds, and accept your answer later. thanks!